# Arduino expected ')' before '{' token

Tags: c++, compilation-errors

```
 for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte{i} < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte{i}, HEX);
    content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte{i} < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
    content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte{i}, HEX));
  }
```

I use this code to get UID of an RFID card, but the error `"expected ')' before '{' token"` comes out. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is a simple C(++) error and not Arduino-specific. To address array elements you should use square brackets (`[`, `]`) instead of curly brackets. Replace all instances of `{i}` with `[i]` and you will be good to go.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a trivial syntax error question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to this site, next time use ctrl-k to align your code.

The problem is in:

```
Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte{i} < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
```

To get the value of an array, use `[i]`, not `{i}`, thus

```
Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
```

(similar to other lines).

To give some additional hints:

- Try to prevent duplicated code by storing the byte into a variable. Now you can use `uidValue` in the subsequent lines.

  uint8_t uidValue = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
- Store 0x10 inside a constant.

So you get:

```
const uint8_t MAX_HEX_SINGLE_DIGIT_VALUE 0x0F;

for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++)
{
    uint8_t uid_byte = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
    Serial.print(uid_byte < LOW_VALUE <= MAX_HEX_SINGLE_DIGIT_VALUE ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(uid_byte, HEX);
    content.concat(String(uid_byte < MAX_HEX_SINGLE_DIGIT_VALUE ? " 0" : " "));
    content.concat(String((uid_byte, HEX));
  }
```

I assume the Serial lines are only for debugging, otherwise you can combine them too.

Comment: Thank you very much, Michel.

Comment: If the answer helps, consider upvoting and if the answer solves your problem, also accept it.

Comment: Michel, if you answer a syntax error question, then at least without syntax errors. I thought you agreed that syntax error questions shouldn't  be answered.

Comment: @Juraj I don't have a compiler at hand ... and I will ask to move the question to StackOverflow.

Comment: they will reject a syntax error question. it is off-topic on SO

Comment: So how can the op get an answer? For a beginner programmer I can imagine it's not immediately trivial to use [] instead of {}.

Comment: to ask a question for every syntax error is not a way to learn codding. a codding course is a much better way

Comment: @Juraj .. However, at least instead of answering a duplicate question could be found. Although I hope if the OP stays interested he will do a course, or at least find out how C(++) syntax works.